# numpy array has incomplete shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some numpy array `s`. I get it in some programmatic way (not really matter how):

```
s.shape
> (20, )
```

However, it actually consists of 20 nested arrays and:

```
s[0].shape
> (100, 100, 100)
```

When I try:

```
s.reshape((20, 100, 100, 100))
```

I get `cannot reshape array of size 20 into shape (20, 100, 100, 100)`. How can I fix it and get array of shape `(20, 100, 100, 100)`?

Comment: That means you are using `s` as a container which is not efficient. Just make `s` a proper numpy array by concatenating its 20 elements

Comment: `s` is an object dtype array.  How did you construct it?  If the element arrays are indeed ALL the same shape, `np.array(s.tolist())` should work.  Or try `np.stack(s)`.  `reshape` can't work across that `object` dtype boundary.